# Java Directory Dialog not terminating

Tags: java

I am writing a Java backup manager for practice as I have never programmed in Java. The code I have works, and when I attempt to edit the source/destination my Directory Dialog opens but is never terminated. It will close, but the console indicated that the program is still active. I've tried a couple things that I've googled to no avail. It is probably something simple, but as I stated before I've never programmed anything in Java until now. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code that I have for the dialog window.

```
public void DialogWindow( boolean getSource )
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();

    ixiDialogShell = new Shell(display);
    DirectoryDialog dialog = new DirectoryDialog(ixiDialogShell);
    dialog.setFilterPath( ixiEngine.workingDir );

    if ( dialog.open() != null )
    {
        if ( getSource )
        {
            sourceText.setText(dialog.open());
        }
        else
        {
            destinationText.setText(dialog.open());
        }
    }

    while (!ixiDialogShell.isDisposed()) 
    {
        if ( !display.readAndDispatch() )
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: what type of component is the dialog in question?

Comment: Is this SWT? Whatever this is, you should use the appropriate tag.

Comment: This is an SWT component.

Comment: Have you tried putting it into main instead of it's own method?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to put it in main instead of its own method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. It was not exiting the while loop. I changed the code to the code below, and it fixed the issue without changing the behavior of my program.

```
public void DialogWindow( boolean getSource )
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();

    ixiDialogShell = new Shell(display, SWT.ON_TOP | SWT.SYSTEM_MODAL);
    DirectoryDialog dialog = new DirectoryDialog(ixiDialogShell);
    dialog.setFilterPath( ixiEngine.workingDir );
    dialog.setText(" Directory Selection ");

    String temp = dialog.open();

    if ( temp != null )
    {
        if ( getSource )
        {
            sourceText.setText(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            destinationText.setText(temp);
        }
    }

}
```

If there is anything that you think I should change here, please let me know.